# Styles aren't applied to the React library I made in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I made a React library https://github.com/deadcoder0904/react-typical/ & added styles to that component in the `examples/` folder but styles aren't applied.

Here's the `example/index.tsx` file:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ReactTypical } from '../.';

const App = () => {
  const hypeText = ['Creator', 'Entrepreneur', 'Doer', 'Lone Wolf'];
  return (
    <>
      <ReactTypical
        style={{
          color: 'red',
          fontSize: 256,
        }}
        steps={hypeText.flatMap(hype => [hype, 5000])}
        loop={Infinity}
      />
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The `style` property is already added to the library in `src/index.tsx` file:

```
export type Props = {
  steps: Array<any>;
  loop: number;
  className?: string;
  wrapper?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
} & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>;
```

I think `React.HTMLAttributes` includes every React HTML attribute so `style` must be available there.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your library accepts any `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>` but doesn't use them nor passes them down.

You need something like this:

```
const Typical = ({ steps, loop, className, wrapper: Wrapper = 'p', ...otherProps }: Props) => {

...

return React.createElement(Wrapper, {
  ...otherProps,
  ref: typicalRef,
  className: typicalStyles,
});
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Does it need to be typed? I mean what's the type of `otherProps` or should I leave it like that?

Comment: No. `otherProps` is either `Props` or some subset of `Props`. Typescript should handle this automatically.